# Cofinite difference sets of integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is there any subset $A$ of integers such that

(1) $A-A\subsetneqq 2\mathbb{Z}$;

(2) the complement of $A-A$ in $2\mathbb{Z}$ is finite?

($A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$, and $2\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of even integers.)

**Also,** is there any set $A$ of integers such that $A-A$ is co-finite (in 
$\mathbb{Z}$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1=0$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+2n$ for $n\ge 2$. Thus,

$$\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle=\langle 0,4,10,18,\ldots\rangle\;.$$

Let $A=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\cup\{-a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Then $A-A=2\Bbb Z\setminus\{-2,2\}$: every even difference greater than $2$ in absolute value is $\pm(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ for some $n$, and every non-zero difference of two members of $A$ is at least $4$ in absolute value.

Comment: It seems that $A=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is enough for the result, isn't it?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand: It is indeed; for some reason I must have been subconsciously restricting myself to subtractions in one direction.